# How to use the column number to reference an Excel column instead of the column letter

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

The following code works:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = True

Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
wb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")

Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
ws1 = CType(wb1.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)  

With ws1
     CType(.Columns("K:XFD"), Excel.Range).NumberFormat = "General"
End With
```

I want to use the column number instead of the column letter.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
With ws1
      CType((.Columns(11), .Columns(.Columns.Count)), Excel.Range)).NumberFormat = "General"
End With
```

Comment: Any error? Expected vs Actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can use an integer. You should just access the `Range` property, passing two `Cell` references.

```
Dim a, b, c, d As Integer

With ws1
    .Range(.Cells(a, b), .Cells(c, d)).NumberFormat = "General"
End With
```

where

[image]

**Here is your specific solution**

```
With ws1
    Dim a, b, c, d As Integer
    a = 1 ' row 1
    b = 11 ' column k
    c = .Rows.Count ' the last row
    d = .Columns.Count ' the last column
    .Range(.Cells(a, b), .Cells(c, d)).NumberFormat = "General"
End With
```

And since `Range` takes objects, you could pass both integer indices and strings to `Cells`. This may be helpful in the future.

```
With ws1
    Dim a, b, c, d As Object
    a = 1 ' row 1
    b = "k" ' column k
    c = .Rows.Count
    d = .Columns.Count
    .Range(.Cells(a, b), .Cells(c, d)).NumberFormat = "General"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I first wanted to understand what it was you were doing exactly so I used this code:

```
With ws1
    CType(.Columns("K:XFD"), Excel.Range).Select()
End With
```

This highlights all the rows from K to XFD.

So with that in mind. If you want to use numbers instead of letters use the following code:

```
With ws1
    .Range(.Cells(1, 11), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).NumberFormat = "General"
End With
```

Again to test that it's doing exactly what you are after you can use this:

```
With ws1
    .Range(.Cells(1, 11), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Select()
End With
```